# Get heap size Vs Get heap size limit

Tags: android, memory-management, runtime, heap-memory

I don't understand the difference between totalMemory() and maxMemory().

Get VM Heap Size by calling:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
```

Get VM Heap Size Limit by calling:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Android documentation:

[`Runtime.totalMemory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime#totalMemory()):

> Returns the total amount of memory in the Java virtual machine. The value returned by this method may vary over time, depending on the host environment.

[`Runtime.maxMemory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime#maxMemory()):

> Returns the maximum amount of memory that the Java virtual machine will attempt to use. If there is no inherent limit then the value `Long.MAX_VALUE` will be returned.

Comment: This is My output for your reference:
Dalvik Heap Size:totalMemory()
2020-05-19 15:20:36.901 3661-3661/com.example.memorytest V/onCreate: totalmem:6 mb 
Dalvik Heap Size Limit:maxMemory()
2020-05-19 15:20:36.901 3661-3661/com.example.memorytest V/onCreate: heaplim:384 mb